# after upgrade laptop goes immediately into hibernation

Tags: upgrade

My old Toshiba M55-S135 laptop works very well with Ubuntu 13.10, but fails when I upgrade (to current version).The upgrade progresses well, but on restart, the computer shows the Ubuntu start screen, then goes immediately into hibernation. Screen remains black after trying to start from hibernation. I reinstalled 13.10 so I could use the computer. How can I successfully upgrade?